# Grails Service Execution Time

Tags: grails

I am writing a new application with may business logic written in different Service.  My workstation is running in very good hardware, so everything is fast.  However, I will deploy the application on a VPS server for testing and possible production.  But VPS has more inferior hardware than my workstation.

When tested in VPS, I wish to keep track which service method are slow.  I wish to be able to log the execution time of each service method call.  I can do it tediously by inserting code in each method for the logging.  Is there a cleaner and easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Spring AOP and define pointcuts around your grails service methods. Time the method and log calls that exceed a threshold.

For one such example see [this blog article](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2012/09/25/how-to-implemnet-aop-profiling-in-grails-application/) implementing basic Spring AOP in grails.